# how to distinct my table rows in asp.net mvc c#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I want to distinct my chat table rows for showing PV's.
Please see the below image:

[image]

Comment: in T-SQL => SELECT DISTINCT ... ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  What does not appear right and what do you think it should look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using T-SQL try like this in your SQL query (unless you are using Entity Framework)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 ChatId
 SendUserId
 ...
FROM
 YourTable;
```

This will select rows with distinct combination of all the fields in query.